# Coffeescript generating blank JS file in Rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

EDIT: A full reboot of the machine running the rails server has fixed this.

I'm getting a strange problem in which one of my coffeescript files is compiling into an empty javascript file. This was a file that had been compiling fine and just randomly stopped working. I can enter anything in the file, even code that should throw an error and it still generates an empty js file.

I have run `rake assets:clean` and I have never run `rake assets:precompile` in my development environment. I've checked the public/assets directory and there is nothing in it. I have also tried clearing my browser cache and that didn't work either.

Here is what is in my events.js.coffee file

```
console.log 'test'
```

And here is what is being output to events.js

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

Here is my application.js.coffee file

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require sugar
#= require foundation
#= require fullcalendar
#= require jquery.ui.all
#= require_self
#= require_tree .

$(document).foundation
```

If anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: @Arel I did restart the rails server but that didn't solve it. I did a full machine reboot and that seemed to fix it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and it was the caching in my browser. I emptied everything and it started working. (That's why probably a full restart worked and not restarting rails server)